# Software for simple sketching in 3D

Tags: software-recommendation, 3d, drawing

I'm a web developer new to the world of 3D and its software but becoming interested post-discovery of WebGL and the amazing Three.js library. Recently I saw an exhibition of Alexander Calder's wire "drawings" (see image below) and was excited to recreate similar things, but digitally.

What I was looking for, in short, is some software similar to Illustrator or Photoshop which provides drawing tools (eg, a pencil, a brush, etc.) that work within 3D space. Ideally these could then be exported as Collada files or similar.

I found a website called [Rompola](http://www.rompola.com/) which is a very basic tool that achieves something very similar to what I wanted but is clearly not feature-rich enough.

So is there such software? Everything I've come across is way more complex than I need and seems geared up for more technical drawings than the freehand things I was hoping to create.

Any thoughts and guidance would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

*Hercules and Lion by Alexander Calder*

[image: Hercules and Lion - Alexander Calder]

Comment: Blender, who cares it has more features. You just need 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with anything exactly like you're looking for. Your best bet might be too look at 3D Sculpting software though. ZBrush is the name brand one while Sculptris is a free one that's also very good. Pixologic (the creator's of ZBrush) purchased Sculptris so no idea if they'll really continue to support it but at the time of writing this it is still freely available on their website stating,

> Enter Sculptris, a fun and engaging way to start off your digital sculpting journey!
>
> If you're new to the world of digital sculpting, Sculptris is the ideal ground on which to get started. If on the other hand you're experienced in CG, we offer you ZBrush.

http://pixologic.com/sculptris/

Comment: I second the Z-Brush and Sculptris recommendations - they would probably provide tools that would get the closest to what the OP is seeking.

Comment: @bravokiloecho sure thing. If you're satisfied please remember to mark this answer correct. Helps us keep the site organized, otherwise the StackExchange robot "Community" will periodically bump it for all eternity.